# how to increase date range of a plot to make room for geom_text at the end of series?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I am trying to add label to my series at the end using `geom_text` and for this I have tried to increase the **x axis range** to make room for series labels but it doesn't increase its range with `scale_x_date`.

**Data**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(scales)

file_url1 <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/rtpcr_test_daily_pct.csv"

rtpcr_test_daily_pct <- read.csv(url(file_url1))

rtpcr_test_daily_pct <- rtpcr_test_daily_pct %>%
  mutate(Updated.On = as.Date(Updated.On))
```

Below is the code I have tried and no matter what value I add to x axis dates using `scale_x_date()` the x axis frame remains the same.

I am not sure what's wrong with the code that I 'av tried below:

```
rtpcr_test_daily_pct %>% 
  
  filter(!is.na(pct_rtpcr),
         pct_rtpcr > 0 ) %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = Updated.On, 
             y = pct_rtpcr,
             col = State) 
         ) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  
  geom_text(data = rtpcr_test_daily_pct %>% 
              filter(Updated.On == max(Updated.On)-1),
            aes(label = State, 
                x = Updated.On , 
                y = pct_rtpcr ),
            vjust = -1,  
            size = 3) +
  
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent,
                     breaks = seq(.1,1, by = .1)) +
  
  expand_limits(y = .1 ) + # 
  scale_x_date(aes(limits = as.Date(c("2021-03-01",max(Updated.On) + 15)))) +
  
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  
  labs(title = "% RTPCR testing Between Karnataka & Delhi- Mar'21 onwards") +
  coord_equal(ratio = 70)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

```
scale_x_date(limits = c(as.Date("2021-03-01"),max(rtpcr_test_daily_pct$Updated.On) + 15))
```

[image]

complete code -

```
library(tidyverse)

rtpcr_test_daily_pct %>% 
  filter(!is.na(pct_rtpcr),
         pct_rtpcr > 0 ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Updated.On, 
             y = pct_rtpcr,
             col = State) 
  ) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_text(data = rtpcr_test_daily_pct %>% 
              filter(Updated.On == max(Updated.On)-1),
            aes(label = State, 
                x = Updated.On , 
                y = pct_rtpcr ),
            vjust = -1,  
            size = 3) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent,
                     breaks = seq(.1,1, by = .1)) +
  expand_limits(y = .1 ) + # 
  scale_x_date(limits = c(as.Date("2021-03-01"),max(rtpcr_test_daily_pct$Updated.On) + 15)) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(title = "% RTPCR testing Between Karnataka & Delhi- Mar'21 onwards") +
  coord_equal(ratio = 70)
```

Comment: thanks @Ronak, i actually tried `rtpcr_test_daily_pct$Updated.On` before posting question here but I guess I didn't remove `aes()` along with that. Thanks again for helping !!